# Install dependency in Grails

Tags: grails

I need to install a dependency but I can't seem able to do so.
The jar I need is this one: json-lib\2.3\json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
I have found it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.3
I tried to resolve the dependency in BuildConfig

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3'

}
```

I also tried in plugins. It is not working.
The error is:
*Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact   net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.3 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)*

I am using grails 2.4.5
I have also thought to use the grails command to look for the dependency on a specific repository but I do not know on what repository I can find this dependency

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3` is from http://central.maven.org/maven2

Make sure you add the repository URL in the list of `repositories` in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

```
mavenRepo 'http://central.maven.org/maven2'
```

There is a newer version of jar file, in case you are interested using that.

Comment: The answer helped me look through this repository but the error was still there. I found the solution posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found the solution to this. By using *grails dependency-report*, I managed to understand the hierarchy of dependencies. I realised that the dependency I really need is the following http-builder

```
+--- org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1
```

|    --- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1
|    --- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3

So, I added to the dependencies section

```
 compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1')
```

Without any additional specific repositories.